# Interstitial I close it and it opens

Tags: admob

I made an app and added an interstitial. I set the display frequency from Admob (5 times in half an hour). Ads are opening. The ad reopens 2 seconds after I press the close button. How can I fix this?

in main.java;

......

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2873523357169249/5651xxxxx");
    reklamiYukle();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            reklamiYukle();
            super.onAdClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
         super.onAdLoaded();
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
```

......

```
private void reklamiYukle() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Don't call *mInterstitial.show()* from *onAdLoaded()*. This causes your ad to displayed as soon as it is loaded, and you are (correctly) reloading when the ad is closed.

You should instead call *mInterstitial.show()* on a natural break point in your app.